# Import static .js in Vue-cli + webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import

I've been using vue-cli since some time now, and still have not fully understood how file loading is done. I've read documentation and some blogs and helped me to deal with it since now.

I'd like to import static .js files with some constants in a component. I don't want them to be bundled at deployment, so they can be found and changed easily, directly in the server if needed without having to rebuild the whole project.

I tried to place them in /public/constants/foo.js directory and point to them using absolute paths in different ways

```js
import FOO from '/constants/foo.js';  // Not working

const FOO = require('/constants/foo.js');  // Not working
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to require files from webpack who is in the project root ?

Comment: Files are in the /public directory (I've noticed it works for static files) and don't want them to be bundled by webpack in the build process.

Comment: What is your problem them ? Can you edit your question ?

Comment: The problem is that import is not working. I noticed it works for image or files' paths, but not javascript imports or requires.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your project arch is like

```
/root
  |__/public
  |     |__/img
  |     |__/css
  |     |__/constants
  |            |__/foo.js
  |            |__/bar.js
  |__/webpack.config.js
```

In your `webpack.config.js` create a new entry like

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './public/index.js'
};
```

Then create a `index.js` file inside your public directory and import your `foo.js`

```
import foo from './constants/foo';
```

Of course your `foo.js` should export something like

```
export default function foo() {
  //
}
```

Hoping that will help you.